# Where to put caching functions in Django?

Tags: django

Whenever I update the SQL database, I also update the Redis cache. Should I put all the Redis logic in models or should I have a new module for that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a caching module to keep your cache logic together.

I prefer to keep my modules in a consistent structure based on how I organise the models module.

So if models contains `car.py` and `driver.py` I'd have those same files in my cache, forms & views modules. Makes it easier to find everything :)